# Can't get my Electric Kettle to boil?

Tags: brewing, electric

I assembled an electric kettle with a 5500W CAMCO heating element.  The element heats water significantly faster than my gas burner ever did but peaks out at 205-210 degrees.  I can take 5 gallons from 60 to 210 in only 9 minutes but cannot get it to boiling.  The circuit breaker is 30amp.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's got to be the element going open at that temperature - 5500W is plenty of power (9 minutes!). I guess this a water heater element, designed to operate at 120F or so, it might even be a 'safety feature'. An inductive ammeter would answer that question very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Kettle have a thermal cut out switch wired in the circuit with the element?
If this is the case the thermal cut out switch switches the element off each time it gets to a specific temp. this is a safety feature and can be bypassed by if you have some electrical knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the $40 Blichmann Brewmometer sticking.  Exchanging it tomorrow.

Comment: You should have simply added this as a comment to your own question.

Comment: wait, the thermometer was sticking? could you not observe the wort to see if it was boiling or not?

Comment: yes, but the element produces bubbles even when the surrounding water is not at 212 or more.