# Bucket Heaters and Condensation safety / Lid considerations

Tags: safety, bucket-heater

**EDIT - After many different attempts, I've learned these bucket heaters definitely shut them self off when the water starts boiling (and turn back on when the water drops somewhat below boiling), unfortunately. IMO they are only useful for HERMS.**

I purchased 3 of these [bucket heaters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BDB4UG) to assist my induction stove boil wort.

The instructions state the following safety warnings:

1. DO NOT COMPLETELY IMMERSE THIS PRODUCT IN WATER. The handle and power cord are not designed to withstand boiling water. Always keep the handle and power cord out of water.

With 2 of them, after 1 hour and 30 minutes, 6.5 gallons of water approached boiling but never got there. Once I attached a lid to the kettle, it began boiling (albeit not that much).

Here is how I attached a lid to it:

[image]

What I'm concerned about is that there is condensation forming on the handle/guard, with or without the lid. The lid simply concentrates the steam to the handle/guard.

Is this safe? I hope to just keep the lid on until it boils and then take it off. I've ordered a third to see if it will boil stronger.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the safety of the heaters, other than suggesting you take the black box apart to see whether it is sealed in any significant way.
In regards to the lid, you really don't want one before or during the boil (if you're using an immersion chiller, you'll want to cover the wort before it gets cool, or contamination could happen). The open lid lets sulfur containing compounds evaporate during the boil.
When you have 3000W available I think it will boil in a reasonable time.

Comment: Wouldn't those sulfur compounds evaporate again after he removes the lid, even if they condensate back into the wort while the lid is on?

Comment: Hey Pepi, when you say " you'll want to cover the wort before it gets cool, or contamination could happen", do you mean to say cover the wort AFTER it gets cool?

Comment: I mean cover the wort with a clean lid when you shut off the heat, and then cool the wort. I actually cheat a little myself, by boiling to wort for 5 minutes while covered, so the steam can sanitize the lid.